# async.waterfall like alternative for async.eachSeries

Tags: node.js, async.js

I have to write some code snippet in node.js where I need to control the asynchronous flow with `async.js`. There is a function in `async.js` called `async.waterfall` which gives opportunity to pass some value to next executing function. My problem is I have to run `async.eachSeries` for controlling the flow over an array, but I can't find any option to pass some value like waterfall. Is there any?

Answer (score 1):

async.eachSeries() doesn't have option to pass on the value but you can you use closure to save the value for the next iteration.  For example:

```
var async = require('async');

(function() {
  var lastValue = 1;

  async.eachSeries([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], function (item, eachCb) {
    console.log('item ' + item + ', last value: ' + lastValue);
    lastValue = lastValue + item;
    eachCb(null);
  }, function (err) {
    console.log('done:' + lastValue);
  });
})();
```

The output would be:

```
item 1, last value: 1
item 2, last value: 2
item 3, last value: 4
item 4, last value: 7
item 5, last value: 11
done: 16
```

As you can see in the output, the current iteration is using the last iteration's saved value.

Comment: Actually I wanted to avoid global state. Is there any way without global state variable?

Comment: if the library call doesn't allow, I don't see how but to use closure.  In this case, it's global but within this module.  You can even wrap around in a function to make it just a variable of a function. I'll modify my answer.